# Remix: Contract exceeds gaslimit even tho blocks have a high enough gas limit

Tags: blockchain, gas-limit, geth-debugging

I am trying to deploy my smart contract to a blockchain that was setup for me. The genesisblock specifies the gaslimit (something around 4mil), however that was not enough for me. Instead of deleting the blockchain, I thought that I could just use the launchoption --targetgaslimit '9000000000000' to increase the blocksize.

Currently blocks allow more than 8mil gas right now, and yet remix doesn't allow me to deploy my smart contract.

Error message of remix: creation of courseManager pending...
creation of courseManager errored: Gas required exceeds block gas limit: 6000000. ...

With this gas limit I can deploy my smart contract to my own testrpc.

Last block of the blockchain I have to use:

```
{
difficulty: 2,

extraData:     "0xd583010703846765746885676f312e39856c696e7578000000000000000000007fc5e622ea5289480afafa74ee82a0462b0282712ea819e981d6291ed961a70a0f5f18c825089ffe5e0f3bafbab0d214ef00fadb5593e3f2acfebdb5597a647301",

gasLimit: 8463002,

gasUsed: 0,

hash: "0xfce7488d0377e360994e56fc946b2c42e257a21615925f4e6bfc373d0f713e6e",

logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

nonce: "0x0000000000000000",

number: 161450,

parentHash: "0xf92210297e1f5320f3b38e23e76e1af022920d158522905abfb466c33f81cf58",

receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",

sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",

size: 609,

stateRoot: "0xebba806e0fde228e4b28f4fd371e289ed5fdd6c91bb03690c49ba1ba2e355431",

timestamp: 1519361254,

totalDifficulty: 322901,

transactions: [],

transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",

uncles: []
}
```